# How reach json values in depth of other levels?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

Assuming that I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "level1" :{
        "type": "x"
    },
    "level2" :{
        "level3": {
            "level3": {
                "type" : "Y"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using `Jackson`, how can I get the type = Y value?

It can be also reached by using `gson.jar`

**What I tried so far is:**

```
ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonContent = "...";
JsonNode root = ob.readTree(jsonContent)
root.path("level1");                      //return results fine
root.path("level2").path("level3");       //not return any results
root.path("level2/level3");               //not return any results
```

Comment: Mandatory question: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) and how it didn't work for you?

Comment: updated, please look at the added code

Comment: You should separate your `key:value` pairs with `,`.

Comment: please show me an example

Comment: Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31677392/1393766) (you may need to refresh this page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, since you are not separating `key:value` pairs with comma `,` as shown in http://json.org

[image]

So change your JSON to

```
{
    "level1" :{
        "type": "x"
    }, <-- add this comma
    "level2" :{
        "level3": {
            "level3": {
                "type" : "Y"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and now you should be able to use

```
JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonContent);
root.path("level2")
      .path("level3")
        .path("level3");
```

---

Using Gson your code can look like

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(jsonContent).getAsJsonObject();
root.getAsJsonObject("level2")
      .getAsJsonObject("level3")
        .getAsJsonObject("level3");
```

Comment: Although I fixed my JSON, I have this comma in my code, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @gamil I suspected that your real JSON was valid since you didn't mention any parsing exceptions in `ob.readTree(jsonContent)` but I added info about comma for clarity since your JSON example wasn't valid. Anyway did you manage to solve your problem with code from this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from traversing tree with `path`, which does work, you may also consider using JSON Path that is directly supported with method `at`.
Something like:

```
String type = root.at("/level2/level3/level3/type").asText();
```